# firewalld not blocking traffic from CIDR

Tags: firewalld

I'm hoping someone can enlighten me on what might be going on with firewalld.

I block possible attacks from the server.  I use rich rules to do so and I've even tested blocking a specific IP but not the whole CIDR.  However, when I know I do not care for that network to reach me I usually block by CIDR.  The example of rich rule

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="120.52.0.0/16" drop'
```

then

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I did this by looking up ip 120.52.96.164 with https://www.countryipblocks.net/ that can provide me the CIDR.

With the example above, I had already blocked this CIDR, but there was an FTPD attempt with an IP in this network.

```
Jul 29 01:20:26 domain.ca proftpd[2250]: 0.0.0.0 (120.52.96.164[120.52.96.164]) - SSH2 session opened.
Jul 29 01:20:29 virtual.smbservices.ca proftpd[2250]: 0.0.0.0 (120.52.96.164[120.52.96.164]) - USER root (Login failed): Incorrect password
Jul 29 01:20:29 domain.ca proftpd[2250]: 0.0.0.0 (120.52.96.164[120.52.96.164]) - SSH2 session closed.
```

So I went to the site and looked up the IP and got the CIDR that was already in the firewalld rich rules with error

Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: rule family="ipv4" source address="120.52.0.0/16" drop

How could it be they were able to attempt a connect to ftpd instead of being dropped as my rich rule was already there for that network?

Comment: [CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) is a concept and  that term can't be used to describe an entity defined by that concept. "net block" would be a much better term.

Comment: Why you aren't using fail2ban?

Comment: My hosting provider are on a OpenVZ with an old Kernel.  I am on a updated centos7 and when using ipset I get error ipset v6.29: Kernel error received: Operation not permitted.  They need to update the parent kernel as openVZ cannot share kernels like KVM.  fail2ban fails trying to add bad attempts to firewalld.  until I can get on newer kernel I'm stuck manually blocking bad ips by "net block" as @sven explained.  But I'm curious as to why I would get a hit from that IP in the net block range...  nothing else fails besides fail2ban in journalctl